# Adding a 'delete from cart' action to my redux store

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to add a 'delete from cart' action to my redux setup. So far I can add items to a whitelist I have set up in my `store` but I'm not sure on how to delete items from the cart. This is my `store`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import  reducer  from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';


const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  undefined,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(createLogger(), thunkMiddleware),
    autoRehydrate()
  )
);

persistStore(store, {whitelist: ['cart']});

export default store;
```

These are my `reducers`:

```
import {ADD_CART} from './actions';
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';

export default Reducer;

var initialState = {
  cart:{},
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
};

function Reducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case REHYDRATE:
                if (action.payload && action.payload.cart) {
                    return { ...state, ...action.payload.cart };
                }
            return state;

            case ADD_CART:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
                }



            default:
                return state; 
    };
}
```

And these are my `actions`:

```
export const ADD_CART = 'ADD_CART';

export function addCart(item){
    return {
        type: ADD_CART,
        payload: item
    }
};

export function removeCart(item){
    return{
        type: REMOVE_CART,
        payload: item
    }
};
```

In my `Cart` component is where I want to have a delete from cart button where you can choose a specific item to delete:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    }

    ...
    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
                {this.countTotal()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { cart: state.cart };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

I want to be able to select an specific item from the `cart` array and delete it. I believe this should be done through an `action` with redux since my array is being saved in my `store`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, just dispatch the `removeCart` action (which you have already defined) from your component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartRemove: (cart) => {
            dispatch(removeCart(cart));
        },
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}
```

and update the state by handle it in your reducer

```
case REMOVE_CART:
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((item) => payload !== item)
    }
```

Comment: I think you are invoking the action in the wrong way. Inside your `Cart` component you can invoke `onCartRemove` action simply with `this.props.onCartRemove(item)`